# Angularjs populating corresponding values for selected option in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have data being passed to my view in following format

id    name     color    type 
1     Ford     red      sdean
2.    Nisan    blue     truck 
........

Following dropdown populates it by name

```
<tr  ng-repeat="p in allautos">                                        
    <td>
         <select  ng-model="p.id"  ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in records"></select>
     </td>
     <td>
         <input type="text" ng-model=p.color />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input type="text" ng-model=p.type />
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do is when name is selected in the drop down I want corresponding values to populate in the input fields of color and type. Please let me know the best way to achieve that. Thanks

Comment: You could try ng-change="p.color=c.color;p.type=c.type" in your select.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```
<select ng-model="p" ng-options="c.name for c in records track by c.id"></select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/m9ubFrYdAgPXMGhfri79?p=preview

This uses a [tracking expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) to help angular to match the auto in the option array.